# Mybatis Spring integration

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I have a web application (JSF and Managedbeans) using Mybatis without Spring and I want to use Spring in this web application and integrate mybatis with spring.

I have my mybatis-config.xml and the mappers.
I have mappers in xml and interfaces with the same name of the mappers un xml.

Then the classes that implements the interfaces are something like that.

```
public class LocalidadPersistence implements LocalidadMapper {

@Override
public List<Localidad> getLocalidades() throws SQLException {
    List<Localidad> listaLocalidades = null;
    SqlSession session = new MyBatisUtil().getSession();
    if (session != null) {
        try {
            listaLocalidades = session.selectList("com.mybatis.mappers.localidad.getLocalidades");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new SQLException("Error obteniendo listado Localidades");
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    } else {
        throw new SqlSessionException("Sesion no encontrada");
    }
    return listaLocalidades;
}}
```

MyBatisUtil code is this.

```
public class MyBatisUtil {
private String resource = "com/mybatis/mybatis-config.xml";
private SqlSession session = null;

public SqlSession getSession(){
    try{
        Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(resource);

        SqlSessionFactory sqlMapper = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
        session = sqlMapper.openSession();
    }catch (IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return session;
}}
```

I have been reading something about Mybatis spring integration but I don't understand all very well. I know that my spring xml must be something like that. I have not put the mappersLocation property because I have read that this is not neccesary since i have defined my mappers on mybatis-config.xml.

```
<context:annotation-config /> 

<context:component-scan base-package="com" />

<tx:annotation-driven />  

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />  
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB" />  
    <property name="username" value="root" />  
    <property name="password" value="" />  
</bean> 

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/com/mybatis/mybatis-config.xml" />
    <property name="transactionFactory" ref="springManagedTransactionFactory" />
</bean>


<bean id="springManagedTransactionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransactionFactory">  
</bean> 

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="registroClimaMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">  
    <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.mybatis.dao.RegistroClimaMapper" />  
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />  
</bean>
```

Also I have no idea about how to use this inside my application after it has been configured with spring. What happen with MyBatisUtil class and the implementation of the interfaces?

Comment: I am not sure whether this article http://www.mybatis.org/spring/getting-started.html  could make sense, but I think it is worth reading carefully.

Answer (score 0):

When you use mybatis-spring, you will get an implementation of mapper interface automatically from the mybatis. So, you can safely use the interface with @Autowired inside any of your spring beans. That's it. Where there is a spring, there a DI.  And yes, with mybatis-spring you don't need MybatisUtil at all as all the task are managed in your spring xml .